# Pegar dados do Object[]?

Tags: java

No debugger eu vi que o objeto recebe ['produto', 210]

```
Object obj = prodRepositorio.somaById();
```

Gostaria de pegar os dados nele mas não funciana cast nem nada.

Já tentei

```
String produto = (String)obj[0];
Long valor = (Long)obj[1];
```

Já alterei para Object[] mas ele o valor fica no obj[0]

Comment: Pode postar qual o código de 'somaById()'? Só com essas informações eu não consigo te ajudar

Comment: `somaById()` retorna um `Map<String,int>`, né?

Comment: não ele retorna um Object[]